# How do I get Flink savepoint ID?

Tags: apache-flink

In the 2 savepoint related REST APIs:

- [POST /jobs/:jobid/savepoints](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/monitoring/rest_api.html#jobs-jobid-savepoints) which triggers an async savepoint operation and returns a trigger ID.
- [GET /jobs/:jobid/savepoints/:triggerid](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/monitoring/rest_api.html#jobs-jobid-savepoints-triggerid) which returns the status of the operation by trigger ID.

The first API takes a parameter `target-directory`, but it is unclear whether it is the exact dir or it is the parent dir within which Flink will generate a subdir whose name is the savepoint ID. Based on my experience with Flink CLI, I think it might be a parent dir, but if that is the case, how do I get the savepoint ID? It is not documented in the 2nd API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by printing out the response. Here are examples of success and failure.

1) success:

```
{
  "status":{"id":"COMPLETED"},
  "operation":{
    "location":"file:/savepoints-dir/savepoint-ad4025-dd46c1bd1c80"
  }
}
```

2) failure:

```
{
  "status":{"id":"COMPLETED"},
  "operation":{
    "failure-cause":{
      "class": "java.util.concurrent.CompletionException",
      "stack-trace": "..."
    }
  }
}
```